# seer gem usage showing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I installed the gem by using

```
$ gem install seer

$ gem update --system
$ gem install gemcutter --source http://gemcutter.org
```

then,added the following line to the  of application.html.erb file.

```
<%= Seer::init_visualization -%>
```

During run, the above line is showing the following error:

```
**uninitialized constant ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::Seer**
```

Can you find a solution to use this pluggin for drawing graphs(not flash based) in rails.

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in Rails 3.  Had to do a couple things to fix
1.  Restart Server
2.  Add Raw to both seer lines.  ie:
<%= raw Seer::init_visualization -%>

If you don't add the raw then you get javascript to the screen .

Now I'm trying to figure out why my data object won't graph?

Comment: hello, the application is developing by using rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, and eventually solved it by adding this:

```
config.gem "seer"
```

to my environment.rb file.

Hope this helps- Adrian